# Supabase triggers : Getting syntax error at or near "select" (SQL)

Tags: sql, postgresql, supabase, supabase-database

Iam trying to insert a new row in `profiles` table when a new user is created in `auth` table using a trigger in the **supabase** dashboard

But when creating the function for the trigger I get  `Failed to create function: failed to update pg.functions with the given ID: syntax error at or near "select"` error

This is the function that is called in the trigger

```
begin
  insert into public.profiles (id,email,user_name)
  values (new.id, new.email, select left(replace(new.email, '.', '-'), charindex('@', replace(new.email, '.', '-')) - 1));
  return new;
end;
```

The profiles table has 3 columns , `id,email,user_name`

the user_name needs to be characters before "@" in an email , and any "." needs to be replaced with "-" , example : `"test.123@test.com" -> "test-123"`

[Screen shot for the created function in supabase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hdIUF.png)

Iam new to SQL and having trouble figuring this out , any help is must appreciated  !

Comment: You dont need `select` in `select left(`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try phrasing using an `INSERT INTO ... SELECT`:

```sql
begin
    insert into public.profiles (id, email, user_name)
    select new.id, new.email,
           left(replace(new.email, '.', '-'), charindex('@', replace(new.email, '.', '-')) - 1));
return new;
end;
```